# Issue in Jboss 7.2.2 migration

Tags: java-8, jboss7.x

I am deploying a WAR file to JBoss EAP 7.2.2. During deployment, I am getting 
"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load generated mapper class com.amadeus.jcp.services.ttr.display.structured.builder.response.selma.mapper.offer.DisplayTripCartResponseOfferQuotationMapperSelmaGeneratedClass"

which is caused by "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amadeus.jcp.services.ttr.display.structured.builder.response.selma.mapper.offer.DisplayTripCartResponseOfferQuotationMapperSelmaGeneratedClass"

It is a selma generated class and available in a jar inside WEB-INF/lib.

Same WAR file is deploying successfully in JBoss EAP 7.1.

As per class loader hierarchy, it should be identified but not happening.

Anybody have any idea of this issue, please help.

Verified standalone.xml and jboss-deployment-structure.xml. Using same version before and after migration except for name space version upgrade to subsystems.

Using Java 1.8.0_191

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: Using Java 1.8.0_191

Comment: Maybe you should try to compile and generate your classes again, now within this JBoss, using maven command clean install.